# Write re-write Rule for Cross domain redirection in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, url-rewriting

I have two website on same project for different countries, one is for uk and another is for us. now i have a page exists on US website and does not exists on UK website. Now i want when users tries to find the page UK site, it will redirect to US site on the same page.

as per my knowledge we can write re-write rule for Sub-domain. is there any way to do cross domain redirection using rewrite rule in web.config.

example ::

**http://www.abc.co.uk/xyz/** is the original URL. I want to redirect it to:

**http://www.abc.us/xyz.aspx**

Please correct if i am wrong, is there any way to make it possible. And one thing i didn't found any link which tell me that it is not possible to make such rule.. that's why i am here to ask you expert guys... any idea and suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can either do a bodge job here, and load the UK site in an Iframe on the US site, or you can use what is known as Meta Refresh.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Please follow <a href="http://www.example.com/">this link</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, "content" is the timeout period for the refresh, 0 being an instant re-direct. Obviously, replacing example.com with your own URL. You can also add sub pages, sub domains, basically any valid web URL.

You could also use a javascript redirect, such as

```
window.location='http://www.example.com/'
```

Edit: 
As for actually doing the redirection in ASP.NET, you could use the following to redicrect the client as soon as the page is loaded:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             Response.Redirect("http://www.abc.us/xyz.aspx");

        }
```

Which should be placed in: Default.aspx.cs

Comment: dear, i know this option but i don't want to use this.. please suggest if you can do it from rewrite rules.....

Comment: @raman Do you mean that you want the client to be able to access the UK site, but see the US site URL in the address bar?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you want something in Web.Config to either re-direct the user or display the US URL in the address bar. AFAIK this is not possible, unless you use the methods named above.